# Automatically display map markers in a map from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet containing a list of tasks to complete, and each task includes an address that specifies the location that work should be performed. Different people can update the sheet with additional tasks as needed.

I would like to be able to display these locations visually on a map, so that users don't need to look up the locations manually. Ideally it would be nice if the map was automatically updated whenever tasks are added or updated.

Are there any tools available for this? I have tried google geosheets which seems to do exactly what I want, but because it displays the map in an iframe, it runs into cross-origin issues so it doesn't work.

I'm open to solutions that are embedded directly into the spreadsheet, or externally such as in a separate tab, but being able to access it from the web is essential.